# Make Xcode to run g++ on linking an object file

Tags: gcc, cuda, g++, xcode4.5

I am trying to build an small sample CUDA code matrixMul.cu in XCode 4.5.2. I did:

1. a custom script which runs nvcc to compile the .cu file to an object file.
2. then let xcode to link it with cuda lib to produce the final executable matrixMul

However, in the linking stage, xcode always runs gcc on the .o file instead of g++, and becos of this it results in error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch x86_64 -isysroot ...
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in matrixMul.o
"std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
  ___tcf_0 in matrixMul.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know how to make XCode to run g++ instead of gcc to link the object file. I have only the .cu file in the project so no .cpp to indicate it's c++. However, I DO choose C++ when I created the xcode project in the very beginning. It runs gcc for me regardless I choose Apple LLVM compiler or LLVM GCC in the build settings.

Thank you!
Gary

Comment: What happens when you tell Xcode that the source file is C++?  (in the first tab of the right pane).

Comment: @trojanfoe: after changing the source to c++ type, xcode runs clang++ for linkage, which gives me similar error msgs:

/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot ...

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in matrixMul.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___tcf_0 in matrixMul.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: What is the `Init` class?

Comment: @trojanfoe: the Init class is the c++ standard library, I believe. There is no Init class in my code. All I know is if I copy and paste the gcc command and replace it with g++, then run it in terminal it builds the executable for me. The matrixMul.cu is taken from CUDA sample code. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I can't force XCode to use g++ for linkage, but has a workaround where I  add -lstdc++ to the "Other linker flags" section, making gcc link the c++ lib for me.

It works for now, but I am not too sure if this the only/best solution. Please let me know if anyone has other solution.

Gary